# Vertically centering a text element inside a rect element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code in a project where I try to center a text element inside of a rect element based on the rect height + widht as well as the width and height of the text. It works fine horizontally but applying the same logic vertically fails.

Aligning the text horizontally is easy. I simply get the bounding box of the text to calculate how wide it is, then I subtract that width from the total width of the box to find how much space will be left inside the rectangle. Then I divide that width in half to know how much space I need to padd my x-coordinate of my text in order for it to be equal on both sides:

My code for getting information of the rectangle:

```js
let rect = document.getElementById("rectangle");
let rectXCoordinate = Number(rect.getAttribute("x"));
let rectYCoordinate = Number(rect.getAttribute("y"));
let rectWidth = Number(rect.getAttribute("width"));
let rectHeight = Number(rect.getAttribute("height"));
```

My code for centering the text horizontally:

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let textBBox = text.getBBox();

let textWidth = textBBox.width;
let horizontalPadding = (rectWidth - textWidth) / 2;
let textX = rectXCoordinate + horizontalPadding;
text.setAttribute("x", textX);
```

However, the issue is when I try to apply similar logic vertically. The way I understand it, a rectangle is drawn with its 0,0 point at the top left corner. Which means positive y equals down, and positive x equals right.
Text seems to be drawn with 0,0 at the bottom of the text, meaning that positive y is up and positive x is right.
So in order to compensate for this I first calculate the bottom coordinate of the rectangle, by adding the rectangle y with the rectangle height.
Then I subtract the vertical padding using the same logic as in the horizontal example. I subtract the text height from the total height of the rectangle and divide it by 2.

See code below:

```js
let textHeight = textBBox.height;
let verticalPadding = (rectHeight - textHeight) / 2;
let textY = rectYCoordinate + rectHeight - verticalPadding;
text.setAttribute("y", textY);
```

The problem is, the text is slightly off center and I cannot for the life of me understand why.
Is there some fundamental that I am misunderstanding in regards to how text is drawn?

I understand that there are other ways to do this, and I have solved it differently in my project, so please refrain from giving examples on alternative ways to solve this. I am just curious to know why this logic fails, I would like to understand what is going on.

Here is a codepen live example with the same code as I've inserted above:
https://codepen.io/Sorry-not-sorry/pen/QWBzwjW

Comment: Hi and welcome @sorry notsorry, I understand that you may want to solve it this way but why do you use JavaScript to center an object? You can use 3 lines of CSS code to just center the text in the div. You first just create a div with text. And in the CSS you give the height, width and the attributes `display: flex;` which enables flexbox for that object. Then you use `justify-content: center;` to horizontally center it and then `align-items: center;`. This is the easiest way to center a text inside the parent-element. Don't make it too complicated with JavaScript.

Comment: Exactly, I realised that I can solve this very easily with css and that is how I did it. But I also like to understand fundamentals, and that is why I posted this question. I want to understand what is happening and what it is that I am missunderstanding.

Comment: The issue is that the text is set at the default baseline. If you add alignment-baseline: text-after-edge; or alignment-baseline: ideographic; (or set the dominant-baseline to ideographic), your code will work fine UNLESS, your text is influenced by CSS (such as setting the body font-size or setting the size of the font with CSS for the text element). A better approach is to set the text x and y to 50% and wrapped it in a group with the rect.  You could then use the `text-anchor-middle` and `alignment-baseline=middle`  properties for centering.  This is most reliable for a single line of text.

Comment: @jme11 Aah thank you! 
I didn't know about that attribute. That works perfectly, I read some documentation regarding it and I think I have a better understanding of how rendering of texts work now. 

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a more detailed explanation here for future readers:

The baseline affects the position of the text within the text bounding box.  Note that the default for the `alignment-baseline` is `baseline`.  Run the snippet below and you'll notice that the extender for letter 'y' goes below the line and the ascender on the letter 'b' doesn't reach to the top of the line above it when the baseline is set to the default.

What's happening in your JavaScript is that the `getBBox().height` is returning the height of the text bounding box, but not the placement of the text within it.  Therefore, if you change the value of the baseline to `ideographic` or `text-after-edge`, the text will be placed fully within the bounding box.

```html
<div  style="display: flex;">
  <div>
    <h2>Dominant-baseline</h2>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 180 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200">
        <path d="M0,15 L150,15 M0,30 L150,30 M0,45 L150,45 M0,60 L150,60 M0,75 L150,75 M0,90 L150,90" stroke="#ccc" />

        <text dominant-baseline="ideographic" x="10" y="30">ideographic</text>
        <text dominant-baseline="baseline" x="10" y="45">baseline y</text>
        <text dominant-baseline="middle" x="10" y="60">middle</text>
        <text dominant-baseline="hanging" x="10" y="75">hanging</text>
        <text dominant-baseline="text-before-edge" x="10" y="90">text-before-edge</text>
        <text dominant-baseline="text-after-edge" x="10" y="15">text-after-edge</text>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Alignment-baseline</h2>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 180 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200">
        <path d="M0,15 L150,15 M0,30 L150,30 M0,45 L150,45 M0,60 L150,60 M0,75 L150,75 M0,90 L150,90" stroke="#ccc" />

        <text alignment-baseline="ideographic" x="10" y="30">ideographic</text>
        <text alignment-baseline="baseline" x="10" y="45">baseline</text>
        <text alignment-baseline="middle" x="10" y="60">middle</text>
        <text alignment-baseline="hanging" x="10" y="75">hanging</text>
        <text alignment-baseline="text-before-edge" x="10" y="90">text-before-edge</text>
        <text alignment-baseline="text-after-edge" x="10" y="15">text-after-edge</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**Warning:** The problem gets more complicated when you're dealing with SVGs in HTML because they can be affected by CSS.  The default font-size of the text element can be overridden by setting the font-size on the HTML body if the text element font-size isn't being explicitly set on the text element using the `font-size` attribute.  Even then, you can have CSS that overrides this such as `text { font-size: 18px }` in a stylesheet.  The `getBBox()` method doesn't know anything about the font-size applied via CSS in order to calculate the height correctly.

### How to center the text reliably

This approach will reliably set the text in the center of the rect regardless of any CSS affecting the font-size:

1. Group the text and rect together if you want to be able to move them from the 0,0 point.  This way you don't have to account for the position of the rect relative from the SVG origin.
2. Set the `rect` `height` and `width`.
3. Set the `text` `x` position to 1/2 of the `width` of the `rect`.
4. Set the `text` `y` position to 1/2 of the `height` of the `rect`.
5. Set the `text-anchor` property to `middle` on the `text` element.
6. Set the `baseline-alignment` to `central` on the `text` element to center the text vertically.  The `central` value matches the box's central baseline to the central baseline of its parent.
7. Set the `text-anchor` property on the `text` element to `middle` to center the text horizontally.
8. Use a `transform` to move the group into the final desired position within the viewBox.

#### Demo

```html
<svg id="viewbox" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="200">
  <g transform="translate(25,25)">
    <rect width="30" height="30" fill="white" stroke="currentColor" />
    <text x="15" y="15" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle"> Hi </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And, of course, this would be even easier to reproduce with JavaScript than your proposed approach, because you only need the rect x and y attributes to calculate the x and y position of the text element.